# Design for Cross-Platform Classes in C#

Tags: c#, architecture, cross-platform

**Summary:** I want to know the best design for creating cross-platform (eg. desktop, web, and Silverlight) classes in C#, with no duplication of code, with the pros and cons of each design.

I'm often writing new, useful classes for one application domain; there's no reason why they won't work across domains. How can I structure my code to make it ideally cross-platform?

For example, let's say I wanted to make a generic "MyTimer" class with an interval and on-tick event. In desktop, this would use the built-in .NET timer. In Silverlight, I would use a DispatchTimer.

Design #1 might be "create a class and use pre-processor directives for conditional compilation," eg. "#IF SILVERILGHT ...". However, this leads to code that is less understandable, readable, and maintainable.

Design #2 might be "create subclasses called DesktopTimer and SilverlightTimer and consume those from MyTimer."  How would that work?

While this is a trivial case, I may have more complicated classes that, for example, consume platform-specific classes (IsolatedStorage, DispatchTimer, etc.) but aren't directly replacing them.

What other designs/paradigms can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest writing `Interface`s that you would simply implement for your platform specific code. Then, the interfaces assure that your code will respect the contracts given by your interface, otherwise there will be a code break (if one member is not implemented).

Besides, within this library where resides your specific timer classes, to stick to your example, I would create a class for each platform, thus using the `DispatchTimer` for Silverlight, and the built-in .NET timer for the desktop version.

In the end, you would end up using only one interface that only its implementers know how to deal with the contract specifically to your underlying platform.

**EDIT #1**

Conditonal design is not an option for a good design. Here is a tool that will help you deal with the `Dependancy Injection`, that is called [`Unity Application Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff663144%28v=pandp.10%29), and is used to deal with such scenario like yours.

You only use an XML configuration that is very versatile to "tell" what has to be instantiated when this or that interface is needed. Then, the `UnityContainer` consults with the configuration you have made, and instantiate the right class for you. This assures good design approach and architecture.

**EDIT #2**

> I'm not very familiar with Dependency Injection, and not at all familiar with Unity Application Block. Can you point to some resources or explain these a bit further?

1. [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 - April 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff632023%28v=pandp.10%29);
2. [Microsoft Unity 2.0 – April 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff663144%28v=pandp.10%29);
3. [Microsoft Unity 2.0 Documentation for Visual Studio 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20110514184716/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=A07F63D6-62D9-4D34-9AAB-5AA2D2D867A4);
4. [Are there good tutorial/walkthroughs for unity that don't use configuration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072094/are-there-good-tutorial-walkthroughs-for-unity-that-dont-use-configuration-files) (SO question on the topic that should provide valuable hints to start with Unity);
5. [Specifying Types in the Configuration File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660933%28v=pandp.20%29);
6. [Walkthrough: The Unity StopLight QuickStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660908%28v=pandp.20%29);
7. [Walkthrough: The Unity Event Broker Extension QuickStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660916%28v=pandp.20%29).

I think these resources shall guide you through your learnings. If you need further assistance, please let me know! =)

**EDIT #3**

> But anyway, the StopLight quickstart [...] seems to imply that the dependency mapping of interface to concrete class is done in code (which won't work for me).

In fact, you can do both code and XML dependency mapping, the choice is yours! =)

Here are some example that you should perhaps inspire from to make the StopLight quickstart use the XML configuration instead of the coded mapping.

1. [Testing Your Unity XML Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/miah/testing-your-unity-xml-configuration);
2. [Using Design-Time Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660935%28v=pandp.20%29);
3. [Source Schema for the Unity Application Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650568%28v=pandp.10%29).

If this doesn't help you get through, let me know. I shall then provide a simple example using XML dependency mapping. =)

Comment: Interfaces are a great suggestion for design #2. But how do I pull it off without conditional compilation? So I would have, in the timer example, a DesktopTimer and SilverlightTimer class that implement IMyTimer; but what does the MyTimer class look like?

Comment: Let's say you got the interfaces that have to be used within your objects. Then, making another project, for example, for your Silverlight-specific code, would be one way to go, thus creating another project for your deskptop version implementers. It is your platform-specific code that will know what to instantiate when an interface method is called.

Comment: The use of `Unity Application Block` might be useful in this case for `Dependency Injection`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Dependency Injection, and not at all  familiar with Unity Application Block. Can you point to some resources or explain these a bit further?

Comment: Unity seems a bit heavy-weight. Or  maybe I'm just crazy. But anyway, the StopLight quickstart (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660908(v=PandP.20).aspx) seems to imply that the dependency mapping of interface to concrete class is done in code (which won't work for me). Or maybe this should be another question?

Comment: You have the option to do it either in the code or in XML configuration. Choose whatever fits best for you, which appears to be the XML configuration alternative. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think interfaces are a good choice here (defining what a timer will *do* without actually implementing it)

```
public interface ITimer
{
    void CreateTimer(int _interval, TimerDelegate _delegate);
    void StopTimer();
    // etc...
} // eo interface ITimer
```

From this, you derive your concrete timers:

```
public class DesktopTimer : ITimer
{
} // eo DesktopTimer

public class SilverlightTimer : ITimer
{
} // eo class SilverlightTimer

public class WebTimer : Timer
{
} // eo class WebTimer
```

Then comes the fun part.  How do we create the right timer?  Here you could implement some kind of platform-factory that returned the right timer depending on what platform it is running on.  Here is a quick and dirty idea (I would make it more dynamic than this, and perhaps implement one factory for multiple kinds of classes, but this is an example)

```
public enum Platform
{
     Desktop,
     Web,
     Silverlight
} // eo enum Platform

public class TimerFactory
{
    private class ObjectInfo
    {
        private string m_Assembly;
        private string m_Type;

        // ctor
        public ObjectInfo(string _assembly, string _type)
        {
            m_Assembly = _assembly;
            m_Type = _type;
        } // eo ctor

        public ITimer Create() {return(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(m_Assembly, m_Type));}
    } // eo class ObjectInfo

    Dictionary<Platform, ObjectInfo> m_Types = new Dictionary<PlatForm, ObjectInfo>();

    public TimerFactory()
    {
        m_Types[Platform.Desktop] = new ObjectInfo("Desktop", "MyNamespace.DesktopTimer");
        m_Types[Platform.Silverlight] = new ObjectInfo("Silverlight", "MyNameSpace.SilverlightTimer");
        // ...
    } // eo ctor

    public ITimer Create()
    {
        // based on platform, create appropriate ObjectInfo
    } // eo Create
} // eo class TimerFactory
```

As I mentioned above, I would not have a factory for every time of object, but make a generic platform-factory that could handle timers, containers and whatever else you want.  This is just an example.

Comment: See Will's comment -- where's the "secret sauce" on how to connect these in the main MyTimer class?

Comment: brilliant, thanks. I'll have a look at Unity and see what seems to have more pros and less cons. I like the straight-forward, "no huge additional libraries" way you've outlined here.

Comment: What you're doing is essentially dependency injection, albeit lightweight. Configuration would presumably done via SomeClass.SetPlatform(blah) or by some XML file or something.

Comment: @ashes999, actually I was thinking that the PlatformFactory would have a Platform enum and set this on construction based on an environment examination.

Answer (score 1):

Go with all OOD you know. I'd suggest creating platform-agnostic (Windows, Mono/destkop, web) domain model. Use abstract classes to model platform-dependant stuff (like the Timer). Use Dependency Injection and/or Factory patterns to use specific implementations.

EDIT: at some point you have to specify what concrete classes to use, but using the abovementioned patterns can bring all that code into one place without using conditional compilation.

EDIT: an example of DI/Factory. Of course you can use on of existing frameworks, which will give you more power and expressivenes. For the simple example it seems like an overkill, but the more complicated the code, the bigger the gain of using the patterns.

```
// Common.dll

public interface IPlatformInfo
{
    string PlatformName { get; }
}

public interface PlatformFactory
{
    IPlatformInfo CreatePlatformInfo();
    // other...
}

public class WelcomeMessage
{
    private IPlatformInfo platformInfo;

    public WelcomeMessage(IPlatformInfo platformInfo)
    {
        this.platformInfo = platformInfo;
    }

    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "Welcome at " + platformInfo.PlatformName + "!";
    }
}

// WindowsApp.exe

public class WindowsPlatformInfo : IPlatformInfo
{
    public string PlatformName
    {
        get { return "Windows"; }
    }
}

public class WindowsPlatformFactory : PlatformFactory
{
    public IPlatformInfo CreatePlatformInfo()
    {
        return new WindowsPlatformInfo();
    }
}

public class WindowsProgram
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new WindowsPlatformFactory();
        var message = new WelcomeMessage(factory.CreatePlatformInfo());
        Console.WriteLine(message.GetMessage());
    }
}

// MonoApp.exe

public class MonoPlatformInfo : IPlatformInfo
{
    public string PlatformName
    {
        get { return "Mono"; }
    }
}

public class MonoPlatformFactory : PlatformFactory
{
    public IPlatformInfo CreatePlatformInfo()
    {
        return new MonoPlatformInfo();
    }
}

public class MonoProgram
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new MonoPlatformFactory();
        var message = new WelcomeMessage(factory.CreatePlatformInfo());
        Console.WriteLine(message.GetMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: DI and Factory patterns sound like the right idea. Can you expound on these a bit more?

Comment: Sure, I added an example. Take a look at Wikipedia for more description of the patterns. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

1) Interfaces with platform-specific class in their own assemblies:  `ITimer` in a shared assembly, and a "WebAssembly" containing `WebTimer`, for example. Then the "WebAssembly.dll", or "DesktopAssembly.dll" are on-demand loaded. This turns it into more of a deployment/configuration issue, and everything compiles.  Dependency Injection or MEF become a great help here.

2) Interfaces (again), but with conditional compilation.  This makes it less of a deployment issue, and more of a compilation problem.  `WebTimer` would have `#ifdef WEB_PLATFORM` around it, and so on.

Personally, I'd lean to #1 - but in a complicated application, most likely you'll end up having to use both because of slight changes in the available parts of the .net framework between silverlight and everything else.  You may even want different behavior in core parts of your app just for the performance issues.

Comment: Dynamically linking assemblies seems to be in the right direction. But conditional compilation is precisely the kind of spaghetti-code mess I would like to avoid. Debugging, maintaining, and just plain understanding that kind of code for any sizable code is a nightmare.

Comment: I agree completely in avoiding it, but for any significantly complex system, you may not be able to completely eliminate it.

Comment: Hence why we're having a design discussion :)

Answer (score 1):

The Model-View-Presenter pattern is a really good approach if you want to separate all of your user interface logic from the actual GUI framework you are using. Read Michael Feather's article "The Humble Dialog Box" to get an excellent explanation of how it works:

http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf

The original article was made for C++, if you want a C# example, look here:

http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/articles/129546.aspx

The Pros are:

- you will make your GUI logic resusable
- your GUI logic becomes applicable for unit testing

The Cons:

- if your program does not need more than one GUI framework, this approach produces more lines-of-code, and you have to deal with more complexity, since you have to decide all through your coding which parts of your code belong into the view and which into the presenter

Comment: My question is about coding libraries, not an actual application.

Comment: Ok, was not so clear to me at first hand. Perhaps you will find my answer helpful either, since the general techniques showed in the articles go in the same direction (how to make reusable classes by using interfaces, mocks etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As others have sugested, interfaces are the way to go here. I would alter the interface from sugestion Moo-Juice suggestion slightly...

`
//Why is this block not formated like code???

public interface ITimer{
void StopTimer();    // etc...

void StartTimer();    // etc...

TimeSpan Duration {get;} // eo interface ITimer

}`

Now you would need to get the ITimer into your class that is using it. The most timple way to do this is called dependency injection. The most common approach to achieve this is called constructor injection.

So when creating a class that needs a timer you pass a timer into the class when creating one.

Basically you do:

`var foo = new Foo(new WebTimer());`

Since that will get complicated quite fast, you can utilize some helpers. This pattern is called inversion of control. There are some frameworks that will help you, like the ninject or castle windsor.

Both are inversion of control (IOC) containers. (Thats the secret sauce)

Basically you "register" your timer in the IOC, and also register your "Foo". When you need a "Foo", you ask your IOC Container to create one. The container looks at the constructor, finds that it needs a ITimer. It will then create an ITimer for you, and pass it into the constructor, and finally hand you the complete class.

Inside you class you dont need to have any knowledge about the ITimer, or how to create it, since all that was moved to the outside.

For different Applications you now only need to register the correct components, and you are done...

P.s.: Be carefull and dont confuse the IOC Container with a service locator...

Links:

http://ninject.org/download

http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html

http://www.pnpguidance.net/Category/Unity.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not have configuration section which will tell your library about the platform of the host application. This you have to set only once in your application to the host config file (web.config or app.config), and rest you can use using Factory method as suggested by Moo-Juice. You can use platform detail over entire functionality of the library.